# Exception 0xe06d7363, when trying to get pointer of tensor data in Libtorch

Tags: c++, libtorch

I'm struggling to write a CUDA operator. The address pointer of the data should be passed into the operator. But I met this exception as you can bellow.

The exception is thrown out like this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <torch/serialize/tensor.h>
#include <ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.h>

int main() {
    // note that whether on gpu or cpu, the exception is the same
    auto options = at::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kInt64).device(torch::kCUDA, 0); 
    auto x = at::arange(0, 10, options); 
    
    // get the pointer of data
    int* x_ptr = x.data_ptr<int>(); // where the exception is thrown out
    std::cout << "x[0]: " << x_ptr[0] << std::endl; // print out 
    
    // ....
    // pass x_ptr into operator function
    // ...
}
```

on cpu, exception: `Exception 0xe06d7363 encountered at address 0x7ffd416f4f6`

on CUDA, `Exception 0xe06d7363 encountered at address 0x7ffd416f4f69`

platform: win10

compiler: visual studio 2022 cl version 19.31.31107

Comment: What line does the debugger report the exception is being thrown from? What kind of exception is being thrown?

Comment: @RaymondChen Hi, I know nothing about assembly code. The exception is thrown out from assembly code `nopl   (%rax,%rax)`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, and I don't know what type of this exception is, because the debugger just show that it's an exception.

Comment: The exception probably didn't come from a nopl. It came from the previous instruction. You should use a C++ debugger, not an assembly debugger. That will help you find the line number, and possibly even decode the exception for you. The exception code e06d7363 means "a C++ exception". You can step into `data_ptr<int>()` to try to find the `throw` statement.